# Parametric area of a region bounded by two curves

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

Let $S(\epsilon)$ be the area of the region bounded by $y=e^x$ and $y=x+1+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a small positive number. When $\epsilon\to0,$ we have $$S(\epsilon)=S_0+\epsilon^\alpha S_1+\dots,\alpha>0$$ Find $S_0, S_1$ and $\alpha$.

For starters, that's how the graphs of $y=e^x$ and $y=x+1$ look like:

[image]

Let's take $\epsilon=0.5$, then we would have the following graphs:

[image]

So for us to find the area of the region bounded by the two graphs, we would need to calculate the following integral $$\int _a ^b (x+1+\epsilon-e^x)dx$$ We have to determine the limits as well, so we have to solve $$x+1+\epsilon=e^x$$ $$e^x-x=1+e$$ $$1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dots - x = 1+\epsilon $$ $$\epsilon=\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dots,$$ which I am not how to use in order to find $x$ in terms of $\epsilon$ and $e$.

How do I continue from here?

I am not sure what the sum given in the problem has to do with the integral and how we should calculate the first two terms. What are $S_0, S_1, \dots$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Claude Leibovici you can use the series reversion approach to get the first couple of terms for the series expansion of the inverse function. Let $f(x) = \epsilon$ and $g(\epsilon) = x$ be the inverse function. Using the approach presented in the link shared by Claude Leibovici you can get $g(\epsilon) = -3 + \frac{13}{2}\epsilon + \ldots$ In order to get this simply put $\epsilon = \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots = \frac{g(\epsilon)^2}{2!} + \frac{g(\epsilon)^3}{3!}$ where you write: $g(\epsilon) = a_0 + a_1\epsilon + \ldots$ and compare powers of $\epsilon$. This allows you to compute the integral as: $\frac{b^2-a^2}{2} + (b-a)(1-\epsilon) + e^a - e^b$. By then using the fact that $a$ and $b$ are roots of $x+1+\epsilon = e^x$ this simplifies to $\frac{b^2-a^2}{2} + \epsilon(b-a)$. Perhaps you could try it from here and see what answer you get, if you get stuck ask again.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the area $S(\varepsilon)$ can be computed exactly. Let's determine (the abscissae of) the points of intersection between the two curves $y = e^x$ and $y = x + 1 + \varepsilon$ in the first place. They satisfy the relation $e^x = x + 1 + \varepsilon$, which is a transcendental equation, but it can solved formally with the help of [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Indeed, one has :
$$
\begin{align}
   e^x &= x + 1 + \varepsilon \\
   1 &= e^{-x}(x+1+\varepsilon) \\
   -e^{-(1+\varepsilon)} &= -e^{-(x+1+\varepsilon)}(x+1+\varepsilon) \\
   W(-e^{-(1+\varepsilon)}) &= -(x+1+\varepsilon) \\
   x &= -\left(1 + \varepsilon + W(-e^{-(1+\varepsilon)})\right)
\end{align}
$$
The Lambert function possesses two real branches within the domain $[-1/e;0]$, namely $W_{-1}$ and $W_0$, in such a way that
$$
\begin{cases}
   a = -\left(1 + \varepsilon + W_{-1}(-e^{-(1+\varepsilon)})\right) \\
   b = -\left(1 + \varepsilon + W_0(-e^{-(1+\varepsilon)})\right)
\end{cases}
$$
It is to be noted that
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0} a = \lim_{\varepsilon\to0} b = -\left(1 + W(-e^{-1})\right) = 0,
$$
as expected, since the $y = x + 1$ corresponds to the tangent of $y = e^x$ at $x = 0$, as depicted by the graphs you provided. Now, the wanted area is given by
$$
S(\varepsilon) = \int_a^b x + 1 + \varepsilon - e^x \,\mathrm{d}x = \left[\frac{1}{2}x^2 + (1+\varepsilon)x - e^x\right]_a^b.
$$
After a few algebraic manipulations and some clean-up, one ends up with the following expression :
$$
S(\varepsilon) = \frac{1}{2}\left(W_0(-e^{-(1+\varepsilon)})^2 - W_{-1}(-e^{-(1+\varepsilon)})^2\right),
$$
which you may Taylor-expand for instance in order to determine the behaviour of $S$ when $\varepsilon \to 0$.