# Area of ​a figure with a parameter that approaches 0

Tags: calculus, geometry, area

$S(ε)$ is the area of the shape, defined by the functions $y = e^x$ and $y = x+1+ε$. $ε$ is small positive number. When $ε \to 0$:
$S(ε) = S_0 + ε^aS_1 + ...., a > 0$
How can I find $S_0, S_1$ and $a$ ?

[Graph of functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af7Bj.png)

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: 3rd term of series? Please provide some more terms in the series

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4887768/1188598 Same question.